# "GetUser" parameters from Active Directory... NOT "current user" but a "specific user" based on selection from a People Picker field.

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

Scenario: We have a "Requestor"(Current User) who completes a form and must select a valid employee from the People Picker field.  This returns validates the employee's "Username". 
We need AD parameters to then fill in addition fields such as: Work Phone, Location, Department, City, State, Zip, etc...

Requirements from manager: The form, designed in SPD 2007, must remain open and the data needs to bee seen by the "requestor", prior to the form being submitted.

We have scoured the internet and have not found anything that helps us with this process. 
We have researched workflow, but it seems it will only work after the form has been submitted.

Infopath is NOT an option for us.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Using: Sharepoint Designer 2007

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to take the java script approach, there are some reference on accessing user profile on WSS3

http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2009/09/20/accessing-user-profile-information-in-wss-3-0-with-javascript/

If those library is insufficient, you may need to create you own web service api for the java script retrieve the information your form needed.

I don't think you can do it just with SPD 2007, below are the things need to do to make it works.

Javascript functions

- get user information (source: built-in sharepoint api using library or custom web service)
- detect the prople picker has value
- fill the fields with the user info